# Add velocity to a sprite in the direction of the mouse, when i push a button

Tags: c++, sfml

```
float avx = 20;//avatar x coordinate
float avy = 20;//avatar y coordinate
float avd = 0;//avatar rotation degree
```

I have it so the sprite is angled in the direction of the mouse(avd).

```
sf::Vector2f av = avatar.getPosition();
    sf::Vector2i m = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
    sx = m.x - av.x;
    sy = m.y - av.y;
    avd = (atan2(sy, sx)) * 180 / pi + 90;
    avatar.setRotation(avd);
```

I need the appropriate x(x velocity) & y(y velocity) values to add to the overall x(`avx`) & y(`avy`) coords. Basically like adding forward momentum to a rocket.

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
    {
        //accelerate toward angle "avd" toward mouse
        //what i can't figure out
    }
```

Sorry if this is the most confusing thing ever, but thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much thought:

variables:

```
sf::Vector2f av = avatar.getPosition();//avatar x(av.x) & y(av.y) coords 
sf::Vector2i m = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);//mouse x(m.x) & y(m.y) coords
float avx = 20;//avatar x coordinate
float avy = 20;//avatar y coordinate
float dx = 0;//x directional fraction
float dy = 0;//y direction fraction 
float dx2 = 0;//x speed
float dy2 = 0;//y speed
float h = 0;//hypotenuse
const float speed = 8; //constant for acceleration(larger the slower)
```

in use:

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))//if W is being pushed
    {
        dx = av.x - m.x;//mouse & av x distance
        dy = av.y - m.y;//mouse & av y distance

        h = sqrt((dx*dx) + (dy*dy));//absolout distance of mouse & av

        dx /= h;//% of hypotenuse that is x
        dy /= h;//% of hypotenuse that is y

        dx /= speed;//% of const speed that x gets
        dy /= speed;//% of const speed that y gets

        dx2 += dx;//x acceleration
        dy2 += dy;//y acceleration
    }
    avx -= dx2;//x momentum
    avy -= dy2;//y momentum
```

braking or max speeds can be attained by manipulating dx2 & dy2.

I hope my commenting makes up for my poor choice in variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Accelerate by `sin(avd)*speed` on the X, and `cos(avd)*speed` on the Y axis!